# How to change inner html of id which is assigned to php

Tags: php

I am using tinymce to store text into database.

The value in database is stored something like

```
<p>testdata&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong><em><span id="coursetitle">{{coursetitle}}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
```

which is assigned to php variable $test;

```
$test = <p>testdata&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong><em><span id="coursetitle">{{coursetitle}}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
```

I want to replace the content where id="coursetitle"

**Is it possible to change the content inside $test variable because that content will be copied to a text file and a file is downloaded.**

I am not displaying on screen so I cant use javascript to change it on
 screen.

I basically want to change {{courstitle}} with the course name value which I get from database

So in the $test I can have multiple {{}} like {{coursetitle}} {{username}} etc and all have seperate values which I get from database.

Comment: I basically want to change {{courstitle}} with the course name value which I get from database

Comment: Actually the duplicate is more complicated than you need

Comment: I assume this is PHP only. Have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php - preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

Comment: @mplungjan Thank You!

Comment: The duplicate is likely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180386/performing-multiple-preg-replace-with-different-search-replace-each-time